# Splitting pandas dataframe through "for" loop cause the Error: KeyError: 'the label [1] is not in the [index]'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an ecel sheet like this:

```
A    B    C    D
          9    someString
          9    someString
1    5         someString
2    6         someString
100  7         someString
101  8         someString
```

Now i am trying to split it into two dataframes:

```
df = df[df['C'].isnull()]
for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
    if (df.loc[i+1,'A'] - df.loc[i,'A']) >= 10:
        df1 = df.iloc[:i+1, :]
        df2 = df.iloc[i+1:, :]
    else:
        pass
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

What I am trying to achieve:

df1:

```
A    B    C    D
1    5   NaN   someString
2    6   NaN   someString
```

df2:

```
A    B    C    D
100  7   NaN   someString
101  8   NaN   someString
```

This cause the problem: `KeyError: 'the label [1] is not in the [index]'`

I guess it is because of the `isnull()` function, but i do not know what to do against this. Could need some help here.

Comment: what do you mean by two dataframe ?

Comment: splitting the pandas dataframe `df` and store the values in two new pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`

Comment: Can you explain what your expected output is? Maybe show us what `df1` and `df2` should look like in this example.

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoid a variable number of variables

Use a dictionary instead. For example, you can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to generate keys for successive dataframes, and [`pd.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) to determine indices where to make splits. The splitting itself can be processed using [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

```
from itertools import count

c = count()
dfs = {}

c_valid = df['C'].notnull()
dfs[next(c)] = df[c_valid]

split_indices = np.where(df.loc[~c_valid, 'A'].diff() > 10)[0]
for df_split in np.split(df[~c_valid], split_indices):
    dfs[next(c)] = df_split
```

Result:

```
print(*dfs.items(), sep='\n'*2)

(0,     A   B    C
0 NaN NaN  9.0
1 NaN NaN  9.0)

(1,      A    B   C
2  1.0  5.0 NaN
3  2.0  6.0 NaN)

(2,        A    B   C
4  100.0  7.0 NaN
5  101.0  8.0 NaN)
```

Comment: It works, also with the edited string column in my question. But unfortunately i don't understand every line in ýour code. I see what you did with `split_indices = np.where....` and `np.split` but i don't see what this `c_valid` is all about. Maybe if you have some time you could explain it to me a little bit more detailed. I would realy appreciate it.

Comment: `c_valid` is to separate out the rows where `c` is null / not null. `df['C'].notnull()` is a Boolean series which we can use for indexing, we take its negative later using the negation `~` operator.

Comment: Ok in my real code `c_valid = df['C'].notnull()` gives me an empty dataframe. At first I have to sort the dataframe after A `df=df.sort_values('A')` and because of this I have to get rid of column C `df = df[df['C'].isnull()]`. But after this your code still works fine, so thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The indices get preserved when you divide two dataframes, if you print the second one you would see that there is no "1" in the index:

```
df2
>>     A    B   C
4  100  7.0 NaN
5  101  8.0 NaN
```

You can use `iloc` to access the first row:

```
df2.iloc[0]
>>A    101.0
B      8.0
C      NaN
Name: 5, dtype: float64
```

Also, a piece of advice: avoid using `for` in pandas. For your case, use `.diff` if you want to split the database when 'A' jumps:

```
ix=df[df.diff()['A']>10].index[-1]
ix
>> 4
df1, df2 = df.loc[:ix-1], df.loc[ix:]
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`. I guess it is because in my real sheet i have an additional column with strings. i did not know that this would be important for this issue. I'll update my question.
Is there an easy fix?